# Bind list from asp.net mvc controller action from querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, binding, model

Is there a way to bind to an action below with the following url

```
/new-event/documents/scoresheets?gameids=124823,124821
```

instead of with

```
/new-event/documents/scoresheets?gameids=124823&gameids=124821
```

**Action**

```
  public virtual ActionResult Scoresheets(int? eventId, int? gameId, List<int> gameIds)
```